# Implicit declaration of strnlen in FreeRTOS

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, freertos, strlen

While developing my FreeRTOS application targeting an ARM Cortex M3 with GCC, using the C99 dialect, I decided to use strnlen, assuming that it's a standard C function and that I just need to include  to use it. The compiler warns me of an implicit declaration for strnlen, making me realize it's not part of the C99 standard. However, since there hasn't been any linker errors, I assume the function does exist somewhere..

What header am I supposed to include in order to use strnlen, if it's not string.h? Most websites online and the man page for strnlen mention including string.h as the header

Comment: IIRC, `strnlen` is not standard `C` - but `strlen` is.

Comment: from the man pages conforming to section: `strlen`: POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, C89, C99, SVr4, 4.3BSD,  `strnlen`: POSIX.1-2008.

Comment: But the linker didn't complain, so it must be there somewhere right?

Comment: No because it's implicitly defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement it yourself, without a particular header.

```c
size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t maxlen) {
    size_t len = 0;
    if(s)
        for(char c = *s; (len < maxlen && c != '\0'); c = *++s) len++;
    return len;
}
```